# Check string length & ignore whitespace

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have some mobile numbers stored in a Oracle DB. I have a stored procedure that carries out some checks around a variety of validations. The stored procedure is launched by a front end Windows application. One basic validation example is ensuring the mobile field is not null.

I'd like to add validation for: check the mobile number is at least 10 characters long, and do NOT count white spaces (leading, after or in the middle) If not, then ignore these mobile numbers.

Example: '188 123 4567' 
'1881234567'
' 1881234 567 '

All thee above numbers should be taken as valid, where as:

'188 123 456'
'188123456'
' 1881234 567 '

Should fail. Can you assist with syntax? I'm still learning PL/SQL.

Here is an extract of the stored procedure I already have in place:

```
AND NOT EXISTS
(  SELECT *
     FROM person_a p
   WHERE p.person_id = sa.person_id
  AND p.mobile_ph_no = sa.mobile_ph_no
  AND pu.a_mobile_ph_no IS NOT NULL
```

)
If the mobile number already stored on the DB is wrong, I just want to ignore it. Not correct it or modify it in any way. Simply if it doesn't meet the criteria, skip over it.

Comment: You say: '188 123 456' '188123456' ' 1881234 567 ' Should fail. Why does '1881234567' fail?

Comment: Should be ' 1881234567 '

Comment: but why should that fail? it's 10 char long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the other answers properly answer what s/he is asking.  S/He says "*If the mobile number already stored on the DB is wrong, I just want to ignore it. Not correct it or modify it in any way. Simply if it doesn't meet the criteria, skip over it.*"

The other answers **do not** ignore invalid numbers, they alter them by removing the whitespace, and then select them.

So, to only query phone numbers in the DB that are 10 digits with no spaces and no other characters then s/he needs to do this...

```
SELECT * FROM person_a
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (mobile_ph_no, '^\d{10}$');
```

So for your query...

```
SELECT *
FROM person_a p
WHERE p.person_id = sa.person_id
AND p.mobile_ph_no = sa.mobile_ph_no
AND REGEXP_LIKE (pu.a_mobile_ph_no, '^\d{10}$');
```

No need for the `IS NOT NULL` part anymore.

Your complete query isn't supplied, looks like you're querying a couple different numbers from different tables, so the select statement above may not be *EXACTLY* what you need, but the main point is, use `REGEXP_LIKE (pu.a_mobile_ph_no, '^\d{10}$')`

Comment: Was able to use a version of this logic, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replace` function. E.g.,

```
select replace('188 123 4567',' ','') from dual;
```

result:

```
1881234567
```

Oracle Database SQL Reference for `replace` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm

See also "Using Regular Expressions in Oracle Database" http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm
Regexp-es are very useful for tasks like this one. E.g. `regexp_count('188 123 4567','[[:digit:]]')` returns the number of digits in `188 123 4567` ignoring all non-digit characters.

Answer (score 0):

Very straight forward code to check the length removing all spaces could be:
    `select length(replace('1881234 567',' ','')) from dual`